# How to make pruned node download an arbitrary block?

Tags: bitcoin-core, pruning, scantxoutset

I want to `importprunedfunds` for addresses related to the wallet (with the help of `scantxoutset`) on a pruned node. The problem is raw transactions are needed for this. I found there were [some](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/10794) [attempts](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/9483) to implement this functionality in Bitcoin Core which never got merged though. What other workarounds could be used without syncing the full blockchain or using third party APIs?

Comment: As of the last release (0.20), you'd have to re-sync the block chain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get old blocks while running a pruned node?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96254/how-do-i-get-old-blocks-while-running-a-pruned-node)

Comment: @pinhead That's definitely interesting, but I wonder if it's possible with just Bitcoin Core, without using a different implementation.

Comment: Conceptually yes but not with today's Bitcoin Core. A key component of BIP157 Neutrino wallets is downloading arbitrary blocks from the network, you could look in to that. It's not as much about using an alternative consensus implementation as it is just writing an application.